# Undefined variable $optionsForModels

Tags: laravel-backpack

Im geting error

ErrorException

PHP 8.1.1

9.37.0

Undefined variable $optionsForModels

What am i doing wrong?

Models

```
class Employee extends Model
{
public function numbers() {
        return $this->morphMany(PhoneNumber::class, 'numberable');
    }
}
class Place extends Model
{
public function numbers() {
        return $this->morphMany(PhoneNumber::class, 'numberable');
    }
}
class PhoneNumber extends Model
{
public function numberable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
      }
}
```

Contorller

```
CRUD::field('numberable')
        ->addMorphOption('App\Models\Employee')
        ->addMorphOption('App\Models\Place');
```

Answer (score 0):

what backpack version are you using ?

We had a similar issue but we fixed it in `5.4.6`. Can you run `php artisan backpack:version` and make sure you are atleast running that version ?

Cheers

Comment: ### PHP VERSION:
PHP 8.1.1 (cli) (built: Dec 15 2021 10:31:43) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.1, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

### LARAVEL VERSION:
v9.38.0

### BACKPACK VERSION:
5.4.7

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue, can you do a `composer show backpack/pro` ? Maybe that's the package that's not up-to-date, maybe `composer update backpack/pro` solve it ?
Other possible cause would be if you are overriding the crud fields in your `resources` folder using the same names, so you don't get the updated files.

Comment: i try to rename folder vendor, clear cache, composer update, no luck

Comment: I just tested on production server and it works, on localhost no luck, all versions are the same.

Answer (score 0):

ok i managed to work this field. But now i have another problem, in docs says:
"Backpack tries to guess which attribute to show for the related item. Something that the end-user will recognize as unique. If it's something common like "name" or "title" it will guess it. If not, you can manually specify the attribute inside the column definition, or you can add public $identifiableAttribute = 'column_name'; to your model, and Backpack will use that column as the one the user finds identifiable. It will use it here, and it will use it everywhere you haven't explicitly asked for a different attribute."
This is not working as it says. If u havent't explicitly write attribute of the column its not working!